# Finish installation of PyMySQL on Mac running Yosemite

Tags: python, mysql, json, macos, pip

I am trying to create a local development space on my laptop, running Apache-MySQL-Python. I have each component installed, but am having difficulty connecting Python to MySQL. I have used these instructions, including installing pip and PyMySQL: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL#installation

When I get to the part that says to enter this:

> $ cp .travis.databases.json pymysql/tests/databases.json

I get this:

> $ cp .travis.databases.json pymysql/tests/databases.json
>   cp: .travis.databases.json: No such file or directory

I can't locate the .travis.databases.json file (I have hidden files showing), even though my $PATH is:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:

Is my path wrong, or is there something else I'm missing? If it makes a difference, all of my tools (installers, pkgs, etc.) are in a folder on my desktop. Apache Server is up and running, too.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install it from source or using `pip`? `.travis.databases.json` is used only for running the test suite and if you're building from source then it is [here](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/.travis.databases.json) in the git repo. If you installed it using `pip` then you'll want to copy that file locally.

Comment: I installed using `pip`. Decided to just make a text file, copy/pasted the code, relabeled it, then dropped it into the right folder. It seems to work now. Thanks!